# change button color action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, colors, actionscript

```
btnPlanet.mouseEnabled = false;
btnPlanet.mouseChildren = false;
```

i have button and it's called btnPlanet, i want to change button color when they are disabled, but the button contain text, that if i change button color using colorTransform, it make my text dismissed, and filled with color that i use from colorTransform, can i change only color of shape in button without change text color? or make it grayscale at least? thank you, i'm sorry if i have bad grammar english

Comment: Can't you use different CSS class for each state?

Comment: Maybe changing the `blendMode` of your button is the right effect for you. Try it out with the blendmodes, which flash provides: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html

Comment: hmm, can you give an example to use blendmodes, cause i'm not really understand how to use that, thank you

Comment: I'd rather redraw the button graphics in this case, or create two containers in the button (layers, if drawing in Flash CC), and assign `colorTransform` property of that container that doesn't contain the text field.

Comment: Depending on the look of the UI, perhaps just setting the whole button alpha to .4 would create a disabled look for you?

Comment: i have tried to use alpha, but it didn't work well, hmm, i'm using flash cs6, i'll try for your way Vesper, to redraw the button graphics

Answer (score 0):

Apply alpha/colorTransform/whatever to everything EXCEPT text field.
Is it your own button or you're using some kind of component?
If it's your own I bet you have something like background for shape and TextField on top of that.
If it's a component I'm pretty sure you should be able to access it as well.

Answer (score 0):

that's not hard.set instance name of your shape in your button for example myShape. Then write:

```
btnPlanet.myShape.transform.colorTransform=new ColorTransform(your colortransform settings)
```